# Segmentation error while reading from text file to a string in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm kinda new to C programming ...  I'm trying to read a user name from the user and another from a text file... the first one is working but when reading from the text file and storing into "user_name" it gives me a segmentation error. what's wrong here?

```
char user_in[10];
char user_name[10];
scanf("%s",user_in);
FILE *users_file;
users_file=fopen("users.txt","r");
fscanf(users_file,"%s",user_name);// segmentation error
```

(EDITED) : 
The file does exist (I've tested it). the first content is a 5 character long string followed by a white space;

```
Sarah Mary Sally
```

Comment: What are the contents of users.txt? If your first line is longer than 9 characters before a new line or other white space you'll be running over the end of your buffer when it puts the null terminator `\0` on the end.

Comment: Does the file exist? Have you check to see if `fopen` is succeeding?

Comment: Please proivde the data file too - quick guess is that it dosent fit into 9 bytes.

Comment: Is `users_file` non-NULL (i.e., did the `fopen()` succeed)? What happens with `scanf("%s", user_in)` if the stdin is taken from the file users.txt (i.e., `./myprog < users.txt`)? What *exactly* is in users.txt (i.e., `hexdump -C users.txt`)?

Comment: The file does exist (I've tested it). the first content is a 5 character long string followed by a white space.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you do not overwrite beyond the allocated array size of `user_name`.

You allocated `user_name` a memory of `10` characters, If your file contains more than the memory allocated for `user_name` then there is not enough space to store that content and it overwrittes the bounds of allocated memory causing an **Undefined Behavior** which can very well lead to a segmentation fault.

Also, there is no error handling in your program. For eg: You should be checking if the `fopen` call suceeded.
In short, whenever you use c standard library functions always check if the function was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

the size of content which the program read from file is over the size of user_name. it would cause buffer overflow and break the function stack.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better giving a size in scanf()

```
scanf("%9s", user_in);
```

and

```
fscanf(users_file, "%9s", user_name);
```

You specify 9 as the length, since the final, tenth character has the value zero to represent the end of the string.

Also, as others have said, check that you successfully opened the file:

```
#include <errno.h>  /* errno */
#include <string.h> /* strerror() */


users_file = fopen("users.txt","r");
if(!users_file){
    fprintf(stderr, "couldn't open users.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Also, scanf() stops at whitespace. If you just want text from a file, use fgets:

    fgets(user_name, user_file);